# GoogleMaps Android app implementing on Monodroid

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

This code is showing the address on a google maps sending the address text to an url and then retrieving it in a Json object, Is there a way to transalate this code to Monodroid using Httppost from apache libraries or not?

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {
Geocoder geocoder = null;
MapView mapView = null;
ProgressDialog progDialog = null;
List<Address> addressList = null;
double latitude;
double longitude;

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.geoMap);

    progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MapsActivity.this, "Processing...",
            "Finding Location...", true, false);

    TextView txtAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);
    String locationName = "Av. Venezuela 1234 Lima Peru";

    txtAddress.setText(locationName);

    JSONObject location = getLocationInfo(locationName);
    Boolean bool = getLatLong(location);
    if(location!=null && bool != false){
        int lat = (int) (latitude * 1000000);
        int lng = (int) (longitude * 1000000);

        GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(16);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);
        mapView.getController().animateTo(pt);
    }else {
        Dialog foundNothingDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MapsActivity.this).setIcon(0)
                .setTitle("Failed to Find Location")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                .setMessage("Location Not Found...").create();
        foundNothingDlg.show();
    }
}




public JSONObject getLocationInfo(String address) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {

    address = address.replaceAll(" ","%20");    

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;

        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        Log.i("JSONOBJECT: ", stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}

public boolean getLatLong(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    try {

        longitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        latitude = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return false;

    }
    progDialog.dismiss();
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost isn't bound, and it's currently very hard to bind your own Java libraries.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the equivalent .NET classes, like HttpWebRequest or WebClient.